# Windows Security Center Service error 1802 showing up in event viewer

Tags: windows-xp, security-center

I have problem with chkdsk. I saw "error 1802" regarding Security Center in the event viewer. Details:

> The Windows Security Center Service was unable to establish event queries with WMI to monitor third party AntiVirus and Firewall.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
>       0000: 8004100a

What could cause this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It could be malware....http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now/157533#157533

Comment: i scan my pc for viruses, they were detected and removed, after this error disappears, but I do not now what exactly cause it.

Comment: Malware caused it, and now its gone due to the removal of it. Be sure you have all windows security updates installed and update to Internet Explorer 8 if you have not already. Do you have Anti-Virus software installed?

Comment: i had esset nod32, now change on avg

Comment: nod32 is the best paid AV, if you want the best free AV use Microsoft Security Essentials.